# How to efficiently configure webpack + gulp + nodemon + react?

Tags: reactjs, gulp, webpack, nodemon

I'll leave my whole gulpfile at end so reading is easier.

I basically have a folder for server files, and a folder for public bundled JS. Originally I only cared about restarting server when modifying server files... but then I realized that would cause a hash mismatch in React when I changed a component to render. But of course I needed to wait for files to transpile or the server would explode on certain things like `import`. Meanwhile I needed to ensure that the server did not restart until the transpile was done, or it wouldn't have the latest code.

All that being said, these ~50 lines seem pretty hacky to me. I feel like I must be missing something in terms of how to do this better - esp in regards to my `ext` config for `nodemon`.

Any suggestions much appreciated

```
var gulp = require('gulp');
var nodemon = require('gulp-nodemon');
var babel = require("gulp-babel");
var webpack = require("webpack");
var webpack_options = require('./webpack.config');
var server;

gulp.task('bundle', function(cb) {
  var compiler = webpack(webpack_options);
  var first = true;

  compiler.watch({}, function(err, stats) {
    if (err) {
      console.warn(err);
    }
    console.warn('Bundle ran ' + new Date());

    if (first) {
      cb();
      first = false;
    }
  });
});

gulp.task('transpile', function(cb) {
  gulp.src("src/**/*.js")
  .pipe(babel())
  .pipe(gulp.dest("dist"))
  .on('end', function() {
    if (server) {
      server.restart();
    }

    cb();
  })
});

gulp.task('default', ['bundle', 'transpile'], function() {
  gulp.watch('src/**/*', ['transpile']);

  server = nodemon({
    script: 'dist/server/init.js',
    // Make nodemon stop actively monitoring for manual restarts when needed
    ext: 'fakefake',
    env: { 'NODE_ENV': 'development' }
  })

});
```